# Finite HMM's and their Digamma matrix

Tags: python, numpy, hidden-markov-models

I've been starting at my textbook for 3 days as well as supplementary Matlab code, and I'm simply not grasping how the Gamma matrix looks when the transition matrix has an exit state.

Usually, digamma would have t-1 elements, and each element would be a matrix of the transition matrix dimension (right?  Digamma_t_ij)... so, say my toy example is

```
A = [[0.9, 0.1, 0.0],
     [0.0, 0.9, 0.1]]

x = [-0.2, 2.6, 1.3]
```

The emission probabilities for state 1 and 2 are modelled by gaussian distributions. I'm disregarding r for the moment, i.e. several sequences.

In my mind digamma should have the shape `np.zeros((sequence_length, self.nStates, len(self.nStates + 1 )))` where the +1 is for the exit state...

Although, here's an exert from my textbook:

[image]

"We therefore supplement the ξr matrix with one additional column", how... what... I feel so stupid :(

This is what I'm getting atm

```
Digamma
array([[[0.06495786, 0.93504214, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.        , 0.06495786, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.93504214, 0.        ]],

       [[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]]])
```

I'm guessing the first two elements are right as the values in each matrix add up to 1, so changing their end column just seems wrong... but filling in the last matrix doesn't seem right either?

I'll add all the variables needed to calculate digamma, incase someone can explain this to me and would prefer not to come up with a toy example:

```
# a_pass from the Forward Algorithm
a_pass = array([[1.        , 0.38470424, 0.41887466],
                [0.        , 0.61529576, 0.58112534]])
# b_pass from the Backward Algorithm
b_pass = array([[1.        , 1.03893571, 0.        ],
                [8.41537925, 9.35042138, 2.08182773]])
# scale variables derived from Forward
c_scale = array([1.        , 0.16252347, 0.82658096, 0.05811253])
# Transition matrix
A = array([[0.9, 0.1, 0. ],
           [0. , 0.9, 0.1]])
# Emission matrix, calculated as getting the pdf for each x given a gaussian dist
B = array([[1.        , 0.06947052, 1.        ],
           [0.14182701, 1.        , 0.81107303]])
# Observation sequence
x = [-0.2, 2.6, 1.3]
# The normalised gamma
gamma = array([[1.        , 0.06495786, 0.        ],
               [0.        , 0.93504214, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: A digamma [looks like an "f" character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma) -- which I don't see here. So which are you talking about? Xi (ξ)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's the one I mean. It's just that the update variables have been called gamma and digamma in a previous course I was doing.